# Letting User Specify Own C# KeyCodes for Making Shortcuts

Tags: c#, keypress, keydown, keycode, keyup

I want to let user press key combination and set that combination to perform an action.  Example:  Control/P

I can capture the keys in the KeyDown event, but it's a bit more complicated because certain key combination should not be allowed, such as Control/C and Control/V, since these are used to perform Windows operations, which I don't want to alter.

Does anyone know of a prepared list that I can use to make sure the user is entering an acceptable key combination?  Somebody did this before, and I am hoping not to have to re-invent the wheel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a blacklist of the ones you don't want to allow them to override.

You can use e.g. [Keyboard Shortcuts for Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/126449) as a reference.